# WordPress Log In Page Reloads and Reloads

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to log in to my site, I am successfully able to do that. But, when a regular user tries to log in, the page simply keeps on reloading itself, and prompting user to enter data again.

If he enters wrong password, then it does tell you that. But, if you enter correct details, nothing happens. Same Log in form again.

I have deleted my .htaccess, re-installed wordpress, disabled all bad plugins, searched a lot on google. But couldn't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have some function for hide wp-admin